# Defined function insists its undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, rsvp-promise

I have simple little program which defines two functions as variables. These functions both return [RSVP Promises](https://www.npmjs.org/package/rsvp) so that they can be chained together as I have done below. I use this pattern often but in this case I'm running into madness ...

```
var opChown = function() { ... };
var opChgrp = function() { ... };

debug('chown: ' + opChown);
debug('chgrp: ' + opChgrp);
// Chain permission operations          
opChown()
    .then(opChgrp())
    .then(function() {
        debug('resolving parent promise');
        resolve();
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        debug('rejecting parent promise');
        reject(err);
    }
);
```

While my debug statements clearly show that the two functions are in fact defined, when I execute them I get an unhandled exception:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function

Please help me losing my mind. Any and all suggestions welcome.

---

For some additional context here is the definition of `opChown`:

```
var opChown = function() {
    return new RSVP.promise(function(resolve,reject) {
        debug('opChown');
        if(options.ignoreChown) {
            resolve();
        } else {
            var chown = shell('chown',['-R', downgradedUser, destDir]);
            debug('chown command executed; user permission is "%s"', downgradedUser);
            chown.on('exit',function(code) {
                if(code !== 0) {
                    var errMessage = 'Build [' + code + ']:' + ' problems changing ownership on "' + destDir + '" directory to ' + downgradedUser + '.';
                    debug('Problem with chown: %s', code);
                    reject({operation:'chown', message: errMessage});
                } else {
                    console.log(' - %s executed, user permissions changed to %s', chalk.bold('chown'), chalk.bold(downgradedUser));
                    resolve();
                }
            }); // end chown
        }
    });
}; // end opChgOwn
```

---

Now based on @bergi's great pointer that the stacktrace is indeed available to me on Node's 'uncaughtException' event, here is the stacktrace which clearly points to the problem being within the `opChown` function rather than the function itself:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at opChown (/lib/broccoli-watcher.js:117:13)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/lib/broccoli-watcher.js:167:5)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:809:12)
```

Comment: For what it's worth, the code sample I have listed above is part of a RSVP promise itself. Note the catch function which calls `reject(err)` ... this is passing the reject to the parent RSVP promise.

Comment: You don't need to do that at all; you can simply return the inner promise from the outer promise's `then()` callback

Comment: From what line do you get the error, with what stacktrace? Please add some debugging details.

Comment: @bergi it is picked up by Node's 'uncaughtException' event: `process.on('uncaughtException', atException);` I don't think there is any stacktrace in the error object that is passed in. I will say, though, that I've narrowed it down to the initial call to `opChown()`. I did this by removing the whole then/catch chain of functions. Same error.

Comment: Node's error objects should have a `.stack` property; try to print it.

Comment: @bergi you are a godsend, it does indeed have a stack property ... not sure how I missed that but no more stumbling around in the dark :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I had expected the error message to be something like `undefined is not a constructor`, it looks as if the line

```
    return new RSVP.promise(function(resolve,reject) {
```

should rather be

```
    return new RSVP.Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
//                  ^
```

Notice that @SLaks spotted a mistake as well: `then` takes callback functions. You probably want to use

```
opChown().then(opChgrp)…
```

Comment: Ahhh capital letters. The bain of my existence. Thanks for all the help @bergi.

Answer (score 1):

```
.then(opChgrp())
```

You just called `opChgrp` *immediately* and passed its *result* to `then()`.

Since it doesn't return anything, you get an error.

Comment: Yes both `opChown` and `opChgrp` immediately return RSVP promises which then results in the first function parameter in `then()` being called. By not stating a second function, you can catch all rejections at the bottom of the stack as I've done with the catch block.

Comment: I have added the full definition of the `opChown` function for some more context.

Comment: In fact, to further illustrate the nature of the problem ... if I remove all `.then()` calls and JUST call `opChown();` I still get the undefined error.

Comment: In fact, `then` must not throw an error if you pass `undefined` - even if it's a common mistake though and the script will probably mis-behave, it's not an error.

Comment: @bergi sorry I'm not following ... what I'm saying is I removed all reference to `then()`. I am simply calling the function but still getting the same undefined error. Basically it seems to be complaining that opChown is undefined (although its clearly not).

Comment: @ken: The reply was to SLaks - the piece of code is a mistake, but not the source of the error you experience. I rather believe that some function that is used in `opChown` is undefined.

Comment: @Bergi ... based on your very helpful pointer about the stack I should be able to sort this and your idea that it's a call within `opChown` looks to be correct.